# Summing a column based on date

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2014. I have a table of tax rates that have effective dates of the rate. There is no end date specified, just effective dates. Each tax rate may have multiple tax jurisdictions that have to be summed to get the effective tax rate. This query works to output all the codes and tax rates in the system at a specified date:

```
SELECT
    Tx.STCCode,
    SUM(Tx.tax) AS 'Rate'
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         TT.STCCode,
         (SELECT TOP 1 TR.Rate
          FROM STA1 TR
          WHERE TT.STACode = TR.StaCode 
            AND TT.STAType = TR.SttType 
            AND '10/31/2017' >= TR.EfctDate
          ORDER BY TR.EfctDate DESC) AS Tax
     FROM  
         STC1 TT) AS Tx
GROUP BY 
    Tx.STCCode
ORDER BY 
    Tx.STCCode
```

Output:

```
STCCode    Rate
--------------------
CT         6.350000
EX         0.000000
MA         6.250000
NJ         6.875000
NYC        8.875000
NYNAS      8.625000
NYNR       8.375000
NYWC       7.375000
NYWP       8.375000
PA         6.000000
PHIL       8.141500
PHILBP     0.141500
RI         7.000000
SOFT       1.000000
```

I have another table of records that includes the date of a transaction and the tax code that I need to calculate the tax rate at the time of the transaction.  If I try and use the above query as a subquery for a tax rate field I can't get the field I need into the where clause of the above query.  Most likely this is due to the subquery in the above sample.

I am mostly a SQL hack, kind of been learning it on the fly. Thank you for any help.

Sample with subquery.  I need the field T1.U_DTSIGNED to replace the hard coded date in the tax subquery:

```
select
T1.U_DTSIGNED,
T.U_SUBJOBID,
T1.U_COID,
T.U_TAXCODE,
(select
SUM(Tx.tax)
FROM 
(Select TT.STCCode,
(Select TOP 1
    TR.Rate
    FROM STA1 TR
    WHERE TT.STACode = TR.StaCode and TT.STAType = TR.SttType and 
'10/31/2017' >=TR.EfctDate
    Order By TR.EfctDate DESC
    ) as Tax
FROM STC1 TT ) as Tx
WHERE T.U_TAXCODE = Tx.STCCode
GROUP BY Tx.STCCode) as 'Rate'
FROM [@NWRCHGORDLINE] T
INNER JOIN [@NWRCHGORDHEADER] T1 ON T.U_COID = T1.U_COID and T.U_JOBID = 
T1.U_JOBID
WHERE T.U_ISTotal = 'Y' and T1.U_JOBID = 17106
Order By Len(T.U_COID),T.U_COID
```

Example Results:

`2017-12-28 00:00:00.000,171060001,31,NJ,6.875000
2017-12-28 00:00:00.000,171060002,31,EX,0.000000
2017-12-28 00:00:00.000,171060003,31,EX,0.000000
2017-12-28 00:00:00.000,171060004,31,NJ,6.875000
2018-01-03 00:00:00.000,171060001,32,NJ,6.875000
2018-01-03 00:00:00.000,171060002,32,EX,0.000000
2018-01-03 00:00:00.000,171060003,32,EX,0.000000
2018-01-03 00:00:00.000,171060004,32,NJ,6.875000`

Desired results, since the NJ tax rate changed effective 1/1/2018 if the DTSigned date is in 2018 it should show the changed rate:

`2017-12-28 00:00:00.000,171060001,31,NJ,6.875000
2017-12-28 00:00:00.000,171060002,31,EX,0.000000
2017-12-28 00:00:00.000,171060003,31,EX,0.000000
2017-12-28 00:00:00.000,171060004,31,NJ,6.875000
2018-01-03 00:00:00.000,171060001,32,NJ,6.625000
2018-01-03 00:00:00.000,171060002,32,EX,0.000000
2018-01-03 00:00:00.000,171060003,32,EX,0.000000
2018-01-03 00:00:00.000,171060004,32,NJ,6.625000`

Comment: in your above query, at some point in it, you should be able to add an 'OUTER APPLY' sub query, it could be used to query the table you are interested in and SELECT your value, your WHERE condition can contain the values from aliases you are working with according to the scope level.  You have to give your sub query an alias.  One useful thing is that it can be a TOP 1 query, so it can avoid introducing compounded multiple rows

Comment: Could you please provide your subquery example? And some data example?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're looking for @ned7077 , but it might be worth your time to look into self joins. Basically you can join a table on itself so you can search using two clauses on the same column. [Here is a response I made about self joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51449731/update-record-for-the-last-week/51450376#51450376)

Comment: @Tyron78 I updated the post.  Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: @PausePause and could you please provide some consumeable example data? Some dummy data for the envolved tables and your expected result? It's a bit easier trying the restructuring of a query if you can execute it. However, on first glance I'd suggest to replace the subqueries with joins - but this is what I wanted to test before posting more details...

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this `CROSS APPLY` does what you want:

```
;with STC1 as (
select STACode = 'CT', STAType ='',STCCode='CT'
union all
select STACode = 'NJ', STAType ='',STCCode='NJ'
), STA1 as (
select Rate = 6.875, STAType ='',EfctDate='2017-01-01',StaCode ='NJ',SttType=''
union all
select Rate = 6.625, STAType ='',EfctDate='2018-01-01',StaCode ='NJ',SttType=''
union all
select Rate = 6.35, STAType ='',EfctDate='2017-01-01',StaCode ='CT',SttType=''
),[@NWRCHGORDLINE] as
(
    select U_COID='',U_JOBID='17106',U_ISTotal='Y',U_SUBJOBID='',U_TAXCODE='NJ'
    union all
    select U_COID='',U_JOBID='17106',U_ISTotal='Y',U_SUBJOBID='',U_TAXCODE='CT'
),[@NWRCHGORDHEADER] as
(
    select U_COID='',U_JOBID='17106',U_DTSIGNED='2017-12-31',U_TAXCODE='NJ'
    union all
    select U_COID='',U_JOBID='17106',U_DTSIGNED='2018-12-31',U_TAXCODE='NJ'
)

select
    T1.U_DTSIGNED,
    T.U_SUBJOBID,
    T1.U_COID,
    T.U_TAXCODE,
    Tax.Rate
FROM [@NWRCHGORDLINE] T
INNER JOIN [@NWRCHGORDHEADER] T1 
    ON T.U_COID = T1.U_COID 
    and T.U_JOBID = T1.U_JOBID
cross apply  ((select SUM(Tx.tax) 
                from (Select TT.STCCode,
                                (Select TOP 1
                                    TR.Rate
                                    FROM STA1 TR
                                    WHERE TT.STACode = TR.StaCode 
                                        and TT.STAType = TR.SttType 
                                        and T1.U_DTSIGNED >= TR.EfctDate
                                    Order By TR.EfctDate DESC
                                    ) as Tax
                FROM STC1 TT ) as Tx
                WHERE T.U_TAXCODE = Tx.STCCode
                GROUP BY Tx.STCCode
                )) Tax (Rate)

WHERE T.U_ISTotal = 'Y' 
    and T1.U_JOBID = 17106
Order By Len(T.U_COID),T.U_COID
```

[image]